# 2 actions at the same time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know how to make a function work while the program is waiting for an input.

I have tried with threading module but it didn't work. Also I've tried with the code below but it runs the function after someone have answered and not while they're thinking the answer.

```
import random

def whileAnswering():
    print("You can do it")

a = random.randint(0, 9)
ans = 2*a
q = ""
q = int(input("Calculate 2 * %d" %(a)))

while q != int():
    whileAnswering()
```

Comment: "I have tried with threading module but it didn't work." You should probably show that attempt and explain how it didn't work.

Comment: Now that the code has been edited; this would be _horrible_ to interact with. CPU loops are actually pretty fast; you'd have your message streaming thousands of times up the screen. You'll need `time.sleep()` to make this sufferable if you go down the threaded route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use threading or multiprocessing to implement this. Here is a code example for you:

```
import random
import time
from threading import Thread


class WaitForUserInput(Thread):
    def run(self):
        # your original code
        a = random.randint(0, 9)
        ans = 2 * a
        q = ""
        q = int(input("Calculate 2 * %d\n" % a))
        # added these lines of code from my side :)
        if q == ans:
            print('You did it!')


def print_message():
    print("You can do it")
    time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    waiting_for_input = WaitForUserInput()
    waiting_for_input.start()

    while waiting_for_input.is_alive():
        print_message()
```

You may want to look into chapter 13 from [this book by Dusty Phillips](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/python-3-object-oriented-programming-third-edition)